# Carousel looks strange in IE11, fine in other browsers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, carousel

I have some carousels with graphic indicators on the following webpage:
http://www.llanoestacadoartassociation.com/membersgallery.html

The carousels work fine on every browser except Internet Explorer. (view the page for yourself in various browsers)

I've tried adding IE11 compatibility meta to the header. I've tried messing with the max-width. I can't narrow down the problem.

```
.carousel {
    max-width:90%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #c9c9c9;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    position: static;
    left: initial;
    width: initial;
    margin-left: initial;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.carousel-indicators > li {
    width: initial;
    height: initial;
    text-indent: initial;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}


<!-- carousel -->
            <div id="carolhammondcarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade mx-auto" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <!-- carousel pictures -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item carousel-item" data-slide-number="0">
                        <img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="1">
                        <img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="2">
                        <img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                     <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="3">
                        <img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="4">
                        <img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel5.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                     <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="5">
                        <img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>

 <!-- carousel thumbnails -->
                <ul class="carousel-indicators mx-auto">
                    <li class="list-inline-item active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carolhammondcarousel">
                        <a><img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel1.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carolhammondcarousel">
                        <a><img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel2.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carolhammondcarousel">
                        <a><img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel3.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#carolhammondcarousel">
                        <a><img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel4.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item" data-slide-to="4" data-target="#carolhammondcarousel">
                        <a><img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel5.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    </li>
                     <li class="list-inline-item" data-slide-to="5" data-target="#carolhammondcarousel">
                        <a><img src="images/members/carol_hammond/carolhammondcarousel6.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <!-- end of carousel -->
```

Comment: Your above code will not give any idea about the issue. Also checking the whole site for finding the issue will be complex for any community member. I suggest you to post the code for your carousel here. so that we can directly try to run it in an IE browser to check the issue. Also try to inform us if you are using this carousel from any reference website. We will try to check it to get some idea about the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't expect anyone to view code for the entire site, I was just linking the actual site so people could view the issue. I will edit the post and add the HTML. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to again made a test with your updated sample. I replace the image URL's as your original URL's will not work in sample. I find that your carousel is not working even with Chrome. I suggest you to post any example which can produce the issue. you can also try to test it on your side to check the result.